# click on ListView send own value into another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

**Resources.java**

```
package com.synergywebdesigners.nima;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Resource extends AppCompatActivity {
    //List view
    private ListView lv;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private String JSON_STRING;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resource);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        getJSON();
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
    }
    String products[] = {"India","Australia","America","SouthAfrica","WestIndia","Dubai"};
    ///showing message
    private void showResources(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_RESULT);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String country = jo.getString(Config.TAG_COUNTRY);
                HashMap<String,String> resource = new HashMap<>();
                resource.put(Config.TAG_COUNTRY,country);
                list.add(resource);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Resource.this, list, R.layout.list_resources,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_COUNTRY}, new int[]{R.id.resource_name});

      //  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_resources, R.id.resource_name, products);

       /* lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Resource.this, TourismBoard.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("mylist",product);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                this.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });*/
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Resource.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"Your Message Fetching..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(Resource.this, "Showing Message", "Please Wait...", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showResources();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ReuestHandler rh = new ReuestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL_RESOURCES);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose Your Category");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "TOURISM BOARD");//groupId, itemId, order, title
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "MICE");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(item.getTitle()=="TOURISM BOARD"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wlcome To NIMA Tourism Board",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent tourism = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TourismBoard.class);
            startActivity(tourism);
        }
        else if(item.getTitle()=="MICE"){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Mice Details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**TourismBoard.java**

```
package com.synergywebdesigners.nima;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TourismBoard extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private String JSON_STRING;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tourism_board);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_tourism);
        getJSON();

    }
    ///showing message
    private void showMesage(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_TOURISM);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String detail = jo.getString(Config.TAG_DETAIL);
                HashMap<String,String> tourism = new HashMap<>();
                tourism.put(Config.TAG_DETAIL,detail);
                list.add(tourism);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                TourismBoard.this, list, R.layout.layout_tourism, new String[]{Config.TAG_DETAIL}, new int[]{R.id.tourism});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                 Toast.makeText(TourismBoard.this,"Your List has been Come Please Wait ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showMesage();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ReuestHandler rh = new ReuestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL_TOURISM+"india");
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }
}
```

I want to send `ListView` data into `TourismActivity.java`.

But I have required this value into String variable .
And I have also a problem In resource `Activity` I want To make Searchable `ListView` But Its Not Work.

Please Tell me How i am Fix This.

Comment: How you want to pass the data to another activity ?, Is there any specific condition that when you tap onto any item in ListView and then the new activity should get start and you want that value there ? and here is a basic tutorial to implement Search Functionality to ListView , 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: I want when I am Click on List Show that value Into Another Activity

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.synergywebdesigners.nima, PID: 30604
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                      at com.synergywebdesigners.nima.Resource$1.onItemClick(Resource.java:74)

Answer (score 0):

There is one lib for converting this arraylist to str & vice versa..that can be used..

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

Then add this for the item click of the listview in your Resource Activity..
For sending arraylist as string to other class

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                //To Convert ArrayList in the string.

                Type listType= new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() {
                }.getType();
                String str = new Gson().toJson(list, listType);

                Intent tourism = new Intent(this,TourismBoard.class);
                tourism.putExtra("list",str);
                startActivity(tourism);
            }
        });
```

And while receiving from other activity

```
    // Receiving the string as string extra
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("list");

   // Define a type for the string that which kind of data the string have
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String, String>>>() {}.getType();

    //Converting the string in arraylist with that type define
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> requiredList = new Gson().fromJson(str, listType);
```

Now you can pass this list in your adapter..
please tell if need more assistance

Answer (score 0):

First Create Json Array and array List

JSONArray id_array;

ArrayList product_id_list;

product_id_list = new ArrayList();

Parse ArrayList into JsonArray

id_array = new JSONArray(product_id_list);

Now You can get List values as String