# Pass ArrayList<IntArray> from one activity to Another Activity Android

Tags: android, kotlin

`var listPackets = ArrayList<IntArray>()`
How do I pass list packets from one activity to another activity

Comment: It is more than 10000 size data

Comment: if the data is large you should persist it instead of passing between activities

Comment: Why so you even need to send arraylist from one activity to another

Answer (score 0):

[Passing a List from one Activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340776/passing-a-list-from-one-activity-to-another)

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
```

In the other Activity:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```

Comment: If arraylist is less in size it works fine, But i have more than 10000 data and each item string length is around 45 characters. If arraylist size is less than 2500 then it works fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58153000/7373632 see the answer